# Migradoc Image Gallery

Tags: c#, migradoc

**Background**

I am currently using Kendo-UI as my front-end library and I was using the [saveAs method](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo/methods/saveas) to generate reports based on the DOM that was being rendered, but ran into some serious performance issues (especially in IE). So I decided that I would handle the PDF generation on the server-side using Migradoc.

**What I'm Trying To Do**

Right now I have a listview ([see demo](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/listview/index)) that essentially represents an image gallery. What I'm having a difficult time with is trying to figure out how to have the image/text go from left-to-right.

**What I've Done**

Here is my current code:

```
// Title
var title = section.AddParagraph("Photos");
title.Format.SpaceAfter = Unit.FromPoint(9);
title.Format.SpaceBefore = Unit.FromPoint(9);
title.Format.Font.Bold = true;
title.Format.Font.Color = new Color(33, 37, 41);
title.Format.Font.Name = "Segoe UI";
title.Format.Font.Size = Unit.FromPoint(11);
title.Format.Borders.Bottom = new Border()
{
    Color = new Color(222, 226, 230),
    Style = BorderStyle.Single
};

// listview
foreach (var photo in _photos)
{
    var photoDocument = _documentService.Get(photo.DocumentId);
    var textFrame = section.AddTextFrame();
    textFrame.AddImage("base64:" + Convert.ToBase64String(photoDocument.ThumbnailBinaryData));
    paragraph = textFrame.AddParagraph(photo.Filename);
    paragraph.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
    if (photo.CreatedOn != null)
    {
        var dateValue = (DateTimeOffset) photo.CreatedOn;
        paragraph.AddLineBreak();
        paragraph.AddText(dateValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    }
}
```

The issue with this approach is that Migradoc is placing the photos vertically and the text basically on top of each other (see image below).

**Question**

How can I make it so that the images go from left-to-right until there is no longer any room in which case it starts to wrap on the next line?

**Update**

I'm able to get the photos to line up left-to-right, but without any text using:

```
var paragraph = section.AddParagraph();
foreach (var photo in _photos)
{
    var photoDocument = _documentService.Get(photo.DocumentId);
    paragraph.AddImage("base64:" + Convert.ToBase64String(photoDocument.ThumbnailBinaryData));
}
```

However, I still haven't figured out how to set the text below the image and have the images appear on the same line.

**Update #2**

After spending a long time thinking about this, ultimately what I did was create a table, calculate the maximum number of columns that can fit on the page, and then dynamically add columns as I go. I'm not sure if this is the right solution or not, but it works for me:

```
if (_photos.Any())
{
    var columnWidth = Unit.FromInch(1.75);
    var maximumColumns = (int)Math.Floor((11.5 - pageSetup.LeftMargin.Inch - pageSetup.RightMargin.Inch) / columnWidth.Inch); // 11.5 (page width) - 0.25 (left margin) - 0.25 (right margin) divided by columnWidth
    var table = section.AddTable();
    table.Style = "Table";
    if (maximumColumns > photos.Count())
    {
        columnWidth = Unit.FromInch(Math.Floor((11.5 - pageSetup.LeftMargin.Inch - pageSetup.RightMargin.Inch) / photos.Count()));
        maximumColumns = photos.Count();
    }

    Enumerable.Range(1, maximumColumns).ForEach(i => table.AddColumn(columnWidth));

    var row = table.AddRow();
    var columnIndex = 0;
    foreach (var photo in _photos)
    {
        if (columnIndex == maximumColumns - 1)
        {
            row = table.AddRow();
            columnIndex = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            columnIndex++;
        }

        var photoDocument = _documentService.Get(photo.DocumentId);
        var photoParagraph = row.Cells[columnIndex].AddParagraph();
        photoParagraph.AddImage("base64:" + Convert.ToBase64String(photoDocument.ThumbnailBinaryData));
        photoParagraph.AddLineBreak();
        photoParagraph.AddText(photo.Filename);
        photoParagraph.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
        if (photo.CreatedOn != null)
        {
            var dateValue = (DateTimeOffset)photo.CreatedOn;
            photoParagraph.AddLineBreak();
            photoParagraph.AddText(dateValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of Migradoc Output]